# php input number box setting value within limit

Tags: php, html

Here is my input number box code.

I want that a person can set the value within 1-5 , that is there is only option to set the value from 1-5.

How i can do this?

It means if i input some number in the box i have to put 1,2,3,4,5 .i cant input some other value in the box

```
echo '<td><input type="number" name = "name[]" ></td>';
```

Here is the table :

```
function do_query($conn, $query)
    {
            $stid = oci_parse($conn, $query);
            $r = oci_execute($stid,OCI_DEFAULT);
            print '<table border="1">';
            print '<tr>';
            print '<td>Rest_Table_ID<td>No_Of_Chair<td>Room_no<td>selected_table<td>time_category<td>Request_Date';
            while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) 
            {
                print '<tr>';
                $num=1;
                $val="";
                foreach($row as $item) 
                {
                    if($num==1)
                    { 
                       $val = $item;
                       $num=2;
                    }
                    print '<td>'.($item!== null ? htmlentities($item) : '&nbsp;').'</td>';
                }

                echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name = "invite[]" value= '.$val.' ></td>';
                echo '<td><input type="number" name = "name[]" ></td>';
                echo '<td><input type="text" name = "date[]" ></td>';
                print '</tr>';
            }
            print '</table>';
    }
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: use javascript to validate input in client side

Comment: @AwladLiton i will disable javascript in my browser and i will input 10 :)

Comment: i said to validate in client side :) of course need to validate in server side also

Comment: You cant stop junk coming from client side, filter it on the server side.

Comment: I guess you should validate on the client side (For Normal Users) as well as one the server side (For Users like @AncientGeek)

Comment: ajax check is better way to validate on both side :)

Comment: @sumitb.mdi you will do the same validation twice client & server side ?

Comment: @AncientGeek, yeah! I mean that there are very few malicious users...for the normal users(major audience) you want to make the website very quick...client side validations are very quick as compared to the server side (for the obvious reasons that you don't have to pass data to and fro from server)...but you also can't risk by avoiding server side validation; you need them too..

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

`echo '<td><input type="number" name = "name[]" min="1" max="5" /></td>';`

or you can add pattern

```
echo '<td><input type="number" name = "name[]" pattern="[0-5]{1}" title="Please only type numbers from 1 to 5." /></td>';
```

The `{1}` restrict the length to 1 and the `[0-5]` will restrict the pattern.

but I'm not sure about browser compatibility. As a failsafe you should definitely validate it server side afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

you can use client side validation by javascript. it will reduce unnecessary requests in the server.
 after that you can validate in server.

in server side(in php) :

Get your value and check that the value is greater or equal 1 and less or equal 5.

```
$value=$_REQUEST['input_name'];

if( is_int($value) && (1 <= $value) && ($value <= 5) {
 //valid
}
else {

//invalid
}
```